# How can I build a proper constructor and destructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

> **Question #1:** How can I build a constructor set the value for `(R,PoF,PoR)`? I am trying to understand how constructor works but I guess I don't quite get it.
>
> **Question #2:** Can I build destructor in this way, instead of the way I used in my program?

```
Circle::~Circle()
{
    std::cout << "The fence would cost " << SwimmingPool.PerimeterP(r) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The road would cost " << SwimmingPool.AreaP(r) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Present by FF" << std::endl;
}
```

I just want the cost to come out by itself, but I don't know how should I create destructor to do so.

**Here is my full code:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"


const double PI = 3.1415926;

class Circle
{
public:
    Circle();
    double AreaP(int r);
    double PerimeterP(int r);
    ~Circle();


private:
    int R;
    int PoF;
    int PoR;
};

double Circle::AreaP(int r)
{
    return ((r + R)*(r + R) - r*r)*PI*PoR;
}

double Circle::PerimeterP(int r)
{
    return (r + R) * 2 * PI*PoF;
}

Circle::Circle()
{
    int R = 3;
    int PoF = 35;
    int PoR = 20;
}

Circle::~Circle()
{
    std::cout << "Present by FF" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int r;
    Circle SwimmingPool;
    std::cout << "Please input the radius of the Swimming Pool." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> r;
    std::cout << "The fence would cost " << SwimmingPool.PerimeterP(r) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The road would cost " << SwimmingPool.AreaP(r) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you guys can explain how to build these two things. I am pretty confused. I don't know how to explain my problems, but I just cannot think these two things thoroughly......

Comment: I don't know what PoF and PoR stand for.

Comment: The program was designed to solve a real world program. PoF stands for Price of the fence, and PoR stands for the Price of the road.

Answer (score 4):

You have:

```
Circle::Circle()
{
    int R = 3;
    int PoF = 35;
    int PoR = 20;
}
```

That function creates three function local variables and sets their values. It does not initialize the members of the class. Change it to:

```
Circle::Circle() : R(30), PoF(35), PoR(20) {}
```

Always prefer to initialize in the initializer list instead of setting the values in the body of the constructor.

---

No, you may not use:

```
Circle::~Circle()
{
    std::cout << "The fence would cost " << SwimmingPool.PerimeterP(r) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The road would cost " << SwimmingPool.AreaP(r) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Present by FF" << std::endl;
}
```

`SwimmingPool` is a variable in `main`. It cannot be used in the destructor. Besides, it does not make sense to print those messages in the destructor. It should simply be

```
Circle::~Circle()
{
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between set the values for variables and initialize the members of the class?      Can you also explain what is the function of {} in 

Circle::Circle() : R(30), PoF(35), PoR(20) {}     Thanks.

Comment: If you don't initialize member variables using the initializer syntax, they are left uninitialized if the type is a POD type. If the type is a class, then its default constructor is called. If the object type is a POD type, it is error prone to not initialize them in the initializer list. If you end up using one of those variables in the constructor before it is initialized, your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: The `{}` is the empty body of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
Circle::Circle() : R(3), PoF(3), PoR(3) {};
```

Define the R, PoF, PoR as const int

The destructor must not throw an exception and generally you want it to release resources acquired by the object. Usually not the best place to be outputting stuff to stdout.

Don't use `std::endl` unless you want to flush the stream. Use `'\n'` instead.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean "Flush the stream"? I am a newbie, so...... cannot understand it......

Comment: @RunshengMa - all the data stored in the stream is passed on to the end point (eg screen) and removed from the stream's buffer. It is normally more efficient to write chunks of data to the end point and use buffering.